# Change DIV content on Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to display a text box when I select an option and when another option is later selected the DIV should change to a select.

This is my code but after selecting it doesn't go back to the text box:

```
<select name="type">
<option value="plane">Plane</option>
<option value="car">Car</option>
</select>
<input class="hideme" type="text" name="name">


$('select').change(
  function(){
    if ($(this).val()=="car") $('.hideme').show();
    else $('.hideme').replaceWith('<select><option>a</option></select>');
  }
).change();
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the select you wish to show and set its css as hidden. so that your jquery will look like this

```
 $('select').change(function(){
    if($(this).val()=="car")
    $('.hideme').show();
 else
    $('.hideme').css('display', 'none');
    $('.hiddenSelect').css('display','block');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

replace your text box with

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

and your javascript should be like this

```
$('select').change(function () {
$("#container").html("");
if ($(this).val() == "car"){
    $("#container").html("<input type='text' name='name'>");
}
else{
     $("#container").html("<select><option>a</option></select>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code will not do what you want since you are replacing it completely with a `select`. So next time you call it, there is no class with `hideme`. Do it this way:

```
$('select').change(function(){
  if($(this).val()=="car")
   $('.hideme').replaceWith("<input class='hideme' type='text' name='name'>");
  else
   $('.hideme').replaceWith('<select class="hideme"><option>a</option></select>');
}).change();
```

Comment: Thanks Sourabh, this worked. What if i need to use an id of a different select field. EG.
`<select id="billing" >`
`<option>Car</option>`

Comment: @Jahswey. As long as the `id` is unique, you can simply use `id` the way you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Your else block replaces the "hideme" element with another select tag. Showing it again will cause no changes.

Keep a separate div for the select tag to be shown an another div for the text to be shown